A new just out of the box Corsair RM1000e PSU makes a high pitch noise. Should I return it?
You can hear the noise in this video. I think this is called coil whine, and it's to be expected with high-power PSUs. But this one is marketed as low noise so I don't know whether I should return it. Previously I only owned a 550W PSU from be quiet! and it didn't make any noise like that.

It doesnt sound that bad to me. Its probably the fan. Have you contacted the supplier?

This does indeed sound like coil whine. This most likely won't be harming anything except your ears :). This can also be worsening as time passes. As I am running a Dell XPS laptop (notorious for coil whine). for a couple of years with coil whine daily. But I would defently try to get the unit replaced with one that doesn't have coil whine if you still have a warrenty on it. It won't guarantee that they will replace it as it's "not broken", but you can always try!
